# Smarter way to truncate strings looks uniform in rails app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, truncate, truetype

Like monospace fonts(looks uniform), i have used below font-family

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
```

I don't want to change fonts, anyway to achieve same width for font using css?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Monospaced fonts take the same space for each letter i.e. i and w use the same width. Where as other fonts only use the amount of space required ( i will take less space than a w).

Comment: @ted no i use rails truncate method, anyway to customize fonts using css

Comment: I see, just take in mind that with 'css truncate' you are able to truncate by width(i.e. 100px) while Rails truncation, most likely, truncates by the string.length(e.g. < 15 chars)

Comment: Ehm... you want every character to take up the same width, whether the font is proportional or not?

Comment: @MrLister fonts are proportional

Comment: I don't think I know what you want.